# Run Only Subclasses of a Type in an Ant JUnit test run

Tags: java, ant, junit

Hi is it possible with Ant to define a target that will only run JUnit tests that are a subclass of a given type.

The scenario is: in the project I have joined we have a large number of Integration tests that are not run separately from the Unit tests, and I'd like to define an Ant task to run them in a separate build stage from the unit tests, and ultimately in a separate Jenkins build.  However, there are no naming or packaging conventions for these Integration Tests so the standard Ant path matching won't work in this scenario.

What I think I need to achieve what I want, is a task def that will allow me to say something like:

`<include name="? extends IntegrationBaseTest"/>`

This is obviously a contrived example, but I belive it communicates what I want.

Has anyone implemented something like this or is it possible with Ant out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with Ant. Perhaps [JUnit categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) can help segregate your tests.

Comment: I'm exceedingly lazy and don't want to annotate 60+ classes.  Do you think it will work by annotating the superclass only?

Comment: No, neither `@IncludeCategory` or `@ExcludeCategory` support annotation inheritance (even if the annotations themselves are annotated with `@Inherited`).

Comment: Marking as the accepted answer, as you're right, it doesn't seem possible to do what I originally asked...